# How to name a constraint which was unnamed during the table creation?

Tags: mysql, oracle, constraint

I had created the table by specifying the columns as primary key and not null without giving them any constraint names and I have populated the data. I want to give names to them now.

How do I do this in oracle or mysql ?

If I can't do this what's the easiest and next best solution?

Comment: I think all those unnamed objects get system names. They show up in the corresponding info views. In case of Constraints/Keys it might even be multiple (PK and Index)

Comment: Is the question about MySQL or Oracle? Please use the appropriat etag only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When working with Oracle, you can find the constraint names (and other details about constraints) by querying USER_CONSTRAINTS.

Example (Oracle 12c)

```
-- table with PK and NN constraints
create table test ( 
  id number 
    generated always as identity start with 2000 
    primary key
, description varchar2( 100 ) not null
);

-- populate the table (optional)
insert into test ( description )
select 'description_' || to_char( level )
from dual
connect by level <= 5 ;


select * from test ;
ID    DESCRIPTION    
2000  description_1  
2001  description_2  
2002  description_3  
2003  description_4  
2004  description_5
```

Find constraints

```
select table_name, constraint_name, constraint_type, search_condition
from user_constraints
where table_name = 'TEST' ;  -- table_name: use upper case!

TABLE_NAME  CONSTRAINT_NAME  CONSTRAINT_TYPE  SEARCH_CONDITION           
TEST        SYS_C0021091     P                NULL                       
TEST        SYS_C0021089     C                "ID" IS NOT NULL           
TEST        SYS_C0021090     C                "DESCRIPTION" IS NOT NULL
```

Rename the constraints

```
alter table test
rename constraint SYS_C0021091 to test_pk ;

alter table test
rename constraint SYS_C0021089 to id_nn ;

alter table test
rename  constraint SYS_C0021090 to description_nn ;
```

Do the constraints have new names now? Yes.

```
select table_name, constraint_name, constraint_type, search_condition
from user_constraints
where table_name = 'TEST' ;

TABLE_NAME  CONSTRAINT_NAME  CONSTRAINT_TYPE  SEARCH_CONDITION           
TEST        TEST_PK          P                NULL                       
TEST        ID_NN            C                "ID" IS NOT NULL           
TEST        DESCRIPTION_NN   C                "DESCRIPTION" IS NOT NULL
```

Data still intact? Yes.

```
SQL> select * from test;
ID    DESCRIPTION    
2000  description_1  
2001  description_2  
2002  description_3  
2003  description_4  
2004  description_5
```

Answer (score 2):

If you do this, you can get the names in MySQL:

```
 SHOW CREATE TABLE table_name;
```